# How to lookup localization when it generates a strongly typed class for you?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I create a resource file, with the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.

So now in my code and razor views I can do:

```
@MyNameSpace.Messages.HOME_LABEL
```

But I also need to lookup the localization by key, like this:

```
foreach(var user in users)
{
    string message = user.type // lookup in localization file somehow??
}
```

How can I get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@MyNameSpace.Messages.ResourceManager.GetString(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do that and make it embedded you have one property that u can set

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture
```

Before processing any request  do the following ( in mvc u can do in filter)

```
ResourceString.Culture = //the user culture
```

Assuming your resx file is named as ResourceString